# Is it really required for a pilot to have good eye sight?

Tags: pilots

My basic knowledge says that it is not necessary for a pilot to have good eye sight,  he can use spectacles.

In an article I came to know that :
The United Kingdom Civil Aviation Authority state the following:

‘An applicant may be assessed as fit with hypermetropia not exceeding +5.0 dioptres, myopia not exceeding -6.0 dioptres, astigmatism not exceeding 2.0 dioptres, and anisometropia not exceeding 2.0 dioptres, provided that optimal correction has been considered and no significant pathology is demonstrated. Monocular visual acuities should be 6/6 or better.’

*Above eye problems are high level of eye defect.

• We should be worried on normal eye problem a serious problem to become a pilot ?

Comment: "*An applicant may be assessed as*": It might be interesting to know what the applicant is applying to.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking a) if any country requires pilots to have good eyesight even without glasses, or b) if good eyesight is important for pilots at all?

Comment: Asking about "any country" is too vague, and nearly impossible to answer since each country has its' own rules.  If you wish to limit it to the UK (which the article is discussing), or somewhere else, please specify so that it can be accurately answered.

Comment: @Lnafziger  there are many countries in the world do it is not possible for anyone to have info of all the country . In this section I think there are many pilots or related to that sector , so everyone will have different laws , condition .

Comment: @Pondlife you are right both

Comment: @user55439 That is exactly my point.  The question, as asked, is too broad to answer with a single answer, which is a requirement of this site.  In our terms, it is "too broad" to answer effectively.  I ask that you please narrow the scope to a particular locality so that it doesn't get closed.  See [ask] for more details.

Comment: @Lnafziger is it ok now ?

Comment: As worded this question is unclear. This may be a language barrier issue. Could you reword or say again your question to help us understand your meaning? help us

Comment: @JWalters thank you I got my answer . :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the guidelines regarding medical qualifications (including eyes) for obtaining a U.S. medical certificate:

1. **From the FAA's "Guide for Aviation Medical Examiners"** ([Link is here)](http://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/app_process/app_history/item17b/)
2. **From FAR Part 67- MEDICAL STANDARDS AND CERTIFICATION** ([Link is here)](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp=&SID=18448b9028a46caf44f37ee5c45f3cb2&mc=true&n=pt14.2.67&r=PART&ty=HTML#se14.2.67_1303)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Users shouldn't have to follow links to see the answer, you should put the appropriate content directly in your post.

Comment: @notts90 - Normally what you suggest is a good idea.  However, the content of the links is significantly large (many pages) and not suitable displaying in the answer space.